# Merge a simple array and nested array according to same keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have array 1 like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Second array would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Bhupat Chippa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Dvs Patel
        )
)
```

I want to merge it the way values would be added to second array with same keys. Desired Output will look like this or some way around so that I can use the Array 1's value with Second Array Only:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Bhupat Chippa
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Dvs Patel
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: A simple `foreach()` loop would do the trick. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Down voted because This is simple and not added any effort.

Comment: actually it had a lot to do with database, i just simplified the question for understandability, any way I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply simple [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to do that

```
$final = [];

foreach($array2 as $key =>$arr2 ){
  $final[$key]['FullName'] = $arr2['FullName'];
  $final[$key][$key] = $array1[$key];
}

print_r($final);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1010437

Comment: I up voted your answer, but please don't encourage people to ask without try or any effort.

Comment: Actually one answer is given which don't give desired result, that's why i give another solution

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays are of the same length, you might use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) passing the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) as the second parameter:

```
$array1 = ["1", "2"];
$array2 = [
    ["FullName" => "Bhupat Chippa"],
    ["FullName" => "Dvs Patel"]
];

$result = array_map(function($x, $y) use ($array1){
    $x[$y] = $array1[$y];
    return $x;
}, $array2, array_keys($array1));

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wqk06)

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Bhupat Chippa
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FullName] => Dvs Patel
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```